# Magento : How to add handle through observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to use `addHandle()`, but using the following generates error:

```
public function HandleMe($observer)

  $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();

  $update->addHandle('handlename');
```

raises a "Fatal error: Call to a member function `getUpdate()`"

Comment: What is the event you are observing?

Comment: or customer_register_success, basically i want to run a script or include a js file, once a new customer gets registered

Comment: the `layout` object is not passed to the event. Try it like @Elavarasan said. But I have a feeling that none of these events work. After the events `customer_save_after` and `customer_register_success` are dispatched a redirect is made. and in the new page that appears your layout handle will not be available anymore. You can try to use those events to set a value in the session and on the next page check if that value is set and add you handle in a different event. Like `controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before`. In there you have access to the layout object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using the  Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate() and used addHandle('handlename') and defined the handle in my local.xml after that, but it did not display it. Is there something wrong I am doing ?. Thanks again

Comment: Like I've said in my previous comment, most probably it won't work because after dispatching the event the page is refreshed. In the new page the events are not dispatched anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load core/layout before you update the layout, So try follow below code,

```
 public function addCustomHandles($observer) {
       $update = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate();
        //Your code here..
        }
```

Or refer below link,

[Link 1](http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/77/Magento-observers-unique-layout-handles-page-views.aspx)

[Link 2](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-layout-update-handles/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using the  Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate() and used addHandle('handlename') and defined the handle in my local.xml after that, but it did not display it. Thanks again

Comment: Still you got same error ..?And try to avoid using local.xml, Always try to put your configs in config.xml  file. And Can you show me your configs (local.xml) and layout handle updates..?. And make sure your observer has triggered..

Comment: in observer.php it is :public function handle_me($observer)
 {
  $update =  $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
  $update->addHandle('custom_layout_handle');
  return $this;
 }

Comment: in local.xml it is <custom_layout_handle>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>file.js</script></action>
        </reference>
</custom_layout_handle>

Comment: and observer does trigger, Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems like you missed many thing..Did you referred "Link 1" as I mentioned earlier ..?If not, please refer that..

Comment: I have followed the new module as per Link1 but probably its placement of the handle in the wrong layout  xml, thats causing the update layout to not appear on the page. I ll have to see, you might be correct.

Answer (score 0):

try using following approach :

First add this to your config.xml in yourcustommodule:

```
<config>
<frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <yourcustomtheme_observer>
                        <class>yourcustomtheme/observer</class>
                        <method>addHandles</method>
                    </yourcustomtheme_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

And then add following method to your observer

```
class YourPackage_YourCustomTheme_Model_Observer extends CLS_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function addHandles($observer) {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
            $update = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate();
            $fertilility = (count($category->getChildrenCategories()->getData())) ? 'parent' : 'nochildren';
            $update->addHandle('catalog_category_' . $fertilility);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

PS : this is only for reference, so that you can check whether you are correctly using observer and handles or not.

Comment: .What is "CLS" that you mentioned in above class ..?

Comment: As i have said this is for reference so that you can correctly create an observer, CLS is nothing I have Mage renamed as CLS in my installation... you replace it with Mage_Core_Model_Abstract.. hope this is fine.